How a Parameterised Query Created In Access Database will be Called Through Vb.net
I Have a Query Created In Access Database with Two Parameters
How Value Can Be Passed To These Parameters Through Vb.net ODBC
e.g
I Have a Query Created In Access Database named Query1 with parameters Q1 and Q2
Or
I Have a Query Created In Access Database named Query1 with parameters ? and ?
and i want to Access Query1 In Vb.net
strQuery = "Select * From Query1"
When I Pass Parameters Through ODBCCommand then it give Error
Two Few Parameters Except 2
just like it
cmdDesign.Connection = connection
cmdDesign.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmdDesign.CommandText = strQuery
cmdDesign.Parameters("S_StartDate").Value = DateFrom.Value
cmdDesign.Parameters("S_EndDate").Value = DateTo.Value

It Works When Parameterised Query is made in vb.net
but if u called parametrised query through a query in vb.net
it gives error

Please see this: ODBC Query with parameters , or switch to oledb if you can.
